# 'Storage space is running low' while I have plenty of space remaining

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, insufficient-memory, storage

I have an LG-D855 smartphone having  16 gigs of internal storage and running Android Kitkat 4.4. Although I have plenty of space remaining, the phone prompts `Storage space is running low.`. I had only installed an obb file of 1.2 gigs, which was of Fifa 14; and a few apps which sum up to around 3 gigs out of the total 16 gigs, yet the phone prompts so.

I deleted the obb files and it freed up around 8.5 GB of memory. Likewise, I guess 3 GB worth of apps filled up whole 16 GB. I have tried factory reset over and over, but in vain. Please help me.

Comment: Recommended first reading for this would be our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info). What makes me wonder a little: Does that error also appear directly after a factory-reset? I guess just after installing your "big apps". So please read the linked tag-wiki – and especially note that there's not just "one big storage", but multiple partitions are in use. The error message only refers to *device internal storage*.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a common question from android users.

The answer is that Android has two type of space: app space and file space. When you install an app, it will use the App space (that is usually around a couple of gbs). When you do a factory reset, you will remove all installed apps (from app space) but file space will not be touched.

A common solution to this problem, is going to Settings -> Apps and try to move as much app as possible to the external sd storage.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to clear the storage cases of each apps and fix the SD card as Downloadable docs, images, music, video etc.
Try to use most usable apps and not use an app in duplicates.
Lastly if you do not get any way then Fix the SD Card as Internal Memory and run the Cellphone by rebooting.
Thanks
Tarik